# aws.s3 Package issues when deploying a shinyapp

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, shiny

I am developing an R Shiny App that will display some data we are storing in an Amazon S3 database.  I managed to narrow down all the different R-S3 Database interaction packages to find my favorite one, called "aws.s3".  When I try to deploy an app with this package included via a `library(aws.s3)` command, I get the following error message:

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 120428...Error in vapply(packages, function(pkg) { : values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[17]]) result is length 0
Calls: <Anonymous> ... writeLockFile -> lapply -> FUN -> data.frame -> vapply
Execution halted
```

The app works exactly as I want when I run it locally, and the person from shinyapps support says she has not been able to replicate my issue when she includes the aws.s3 package in her Shiny Apps.  Even when I copy-paste the entire source code of aws.s3 into the app, and remove the `library(aws.s3)` command, I still get the same error message.  Googling this error message got me absolutely nowhere.

So, I've managed to narrow the problem down to the tree of package dependencies.  It is not an issue with my app code, because I also tried to deploy a totally blank application with this package included, but it led to the same error message.  Is there a way to find out which packages in my package directory were installed incorrectly for a shinyapps deployment, or a way to debug the deployment process, so I can identify which package in the dependency tree is giving me problems, or even a way to just look at the dependencies of aws.s3 so I can uninstall and reinstall them until I find a problem?

Thank you to whoever reads all of this!

Comment: For your last question, `aws.s3`'s dependencies are in its ["DESCRIPTION" file](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3/blob/master/DESCRIPTION). Sorry I can't help with the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Update: aws.s3 is now on CRAN, so just install from there.

---

Apparently only packages that are on CRAN or installed on your local system using `devtools::install_github()` will be usable with Shiny. You should be able to reinstall using devtools and get this working.